# How to listen UDP and make use of PHP

Tags: php, linux, sockets, udp

I have to build up a system which listens for requests from a GPS device which is only capable of sending UDP requests. Then I am going to analyze requests hopefully by PHP if it is possible.

I do not know where to start. What do I need? Can I make use of PHP? Would it be reliable to use PHP? Can I just adjust Apache for listening UDP requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I do not know where to start.*

You need a notion of an overall program design, and, as @karim79 pointed out, an understanding of socket programming APIs for your chosen language.

> *Can I just adjust Apache for listening UDP requests?*

Do you mean the Apache `httpd`?  The short answer is "no."

Use something like PEAR's [`System_Daemon`](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon/) instead.

The long answer is "yes, that is possible."  Particularly with modular plugins exposing the `httpd`'s internals, you can do Just About Anything You Want (tm) (see, for instance, `mod_perl`).  You could beat `httpd` into a sort of application server for a long-running (set of?) PHP process(es) which are not themselves intrinsically HTTP-driven.

The better answer of the two is, again, "no." :)

Comment: System_Daemon looks pretty! I am going to give it a try. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

By all accounts I think PHP should be fine for that, but I haven't done anything like that myself. You will need to look into socket programming, here's a tutorial:

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Socket-Programming-With-PHP/

Comment: Thank you, I will dive into socket programming and figure out if I can make use of it.

Answer (score 2):

You could just have your PHP script invoked by `inetd`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, PHP supports a set of [Socket Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php) that allow you to deal with UDP, I've used them myself to build a NSLookup class which I could specify the name server (all in UDP) and a Ping class (RAW/ICMP). It works just like the standard C/C++ socket library. But I don't really think using Apache+PHP is a good choice to build those things. If you want to stick with PHP, its better to script it as a console application.

Comment: Yes you are right. I should manage it to be a console application.